# A problem about subadditive set functions

Tags: measure-theory, set-theory

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{A})$ be a measurable space, and let $\mu: \mathcal{A} \to [0,+\infty)$ be a monotone subadditive set function. Let moroever $A_1, A_2, \ldots \in \mathcal{A}$ be a sequence of measurable sets. It is easy to prove that $\mu(A_n) \to 0 \Rightarrow \mu(A_n^c) \to \mu(\Omega)$. On the contrary, I am not able neither to prove the opposite implication, namely $\mu(A_n) \to \mu(\Omega) \Rightarrow \mu(A_n^c) \to 0$, nor to find an example violating it. Can someone find either one or the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not true that $\mu(A_n) \to \mu(\Omega) \implies \mu(A_n^c) \to 0$. Consider $\mathbb{R}$ endowed with the Lebesgue $\sigma$-algebra. Let $A_n = [0,n]$. Then $\mu(A_n) = n \to +\infty = \mu(\mathbb{R})$, but $\mu(A_n^c) = +\infty$ for all $n$.

Comment: Very well. The codomain of the measure is [0,+oo] rather than [0, +oo) as in my problem, but your example can be easily adapted to my purposes. Thank you very much!

Comment: Sure,_____sorry